# Firebase Chat in Xamarin

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a chat app in Xamarin.Android, using this tutorial:
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/real-time-android-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial/

However, not everything that there is in the Java code appears to be in Xamarin.
For instance:

```
 Firebase reference1;
 Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
 reference1 = new Firebase("https://androidchatapp-76776.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
```

Even though I added all packages of Firebase that are needed, I still can't make a variable of 'Firebase'.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is using the deprecated `com.firebase:firebase-client-android` (`2.5.2`) Java package (this is from before Google purchased Firebase).

The newer `com.google.firebase:firebase-database` corresponds to the Nuget package `Xamarin.Firebase.Database`

**Note:** The latest Java version of that package is I write this is `11.6.0`, Xamarin does not a package for that, but does have a beta package `60.1142.0-beta2` (Java version `11.4.2`).

Something like this using the old Firebase Java client:

```
Firebase reference1;
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
reference1 = new Firebase("https://androidchatapp-76776.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
```

Becomes this using the new Java package (but in C#) becomes:

```
DatabaseReference reference1, reference2;

FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReferenceFromUrl(firebaseURL);
reference2 = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReferenceFromUrl(firebaseURL);
```

re: [Upgrade your Android app from Firebase.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)